# Accessing JSON with integers as keys

Tags: json, bootstrap-vue

The JSON looks like this:

```
"awards": [
   "awardsAtLevel": {
       "1": "Gold",
       "3": "Gold",
       "5": "Gold",
       "7": "Gold"
   }
]
```

so I'd assume I should just use the bracket syntax:

```
...awards.awardsAtLevel["1"]
```

But this doesn't get the data.

My full array looks like so:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
      "awards": [
            "awardsAtLevel": {
               "1": "Gold",
               ...
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried:

```
...awardsAtLevel["1"].text
```

as well, but this doesn't work either.

```
awards.awardsAtLevel
```

*does* print the entire array.

The context is I'm getting data to make a b-table in bootstrap vue:

```
<template v-slot:cell(dmg)="rewards">
        {{rewards.item.awards.awardsAtLevel["1"] && rewards.item.awards.awardsAtLevel["1"] ? rewards.item.awards.awardsAtLevel["1"]: ""}}
</template>
```

Also, sorry if this is a common question. I couldn't find other questions where the bracket notation didn't work.

Comment: But is 'awardsAtLevel' or 'awardsAtLavel'?

Comment: I assume, you are working with javascript. In that case, how can you have a json object inside square brackets?

Comment: awardsAtLevel xD

Comment: I'm working in Vue.js - but javascript is the language for handling non-html markup.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, as @DeepakTerse said, you can't have object key inside square brackets (array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON structure is invalid, it supposed to be

```
"awards": {
   "awardsAtLevel": {
       "1": "Gold",
       "3": "Gold",
       "5": "Gold",
       "7": "Gold"
   }
}
```

(using curly bracket, not squared)

And to show the data, you can do:

```js
{{ awards.awardsAtLevel["1"] }}
```

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-brook-x7wg6?file=/src/App.vue)